# Keras metrics: calculating the results of only one class in binary classification

Tags: keras, metrics

I have a binary classification task, where I would be interesting in getting the accuracy with respect to only the 1s: i.e., while evaluating a model (in the training phase), I would like Keras to return (as a metric) only the number of correct 1s over the the total number of 1s (i.e., 0s are simply ignored): is there a Keras metric doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is recall, assuming '1' as the positive class:

```
recall = true_positive / (true_positive + false_negative)
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall

Comment: true positives can be either 1 or 0, so I do not think that Recall is appropriate